# ¿Como ejecutar comandos adb desde mi App?

Tags: android

Quiero ejecutar una serie de comandos adb una de ellos es obtener la ruta de apps del usuario, pero no se si es que se puede colocar comandos adb en mi app. Si sabe por favor ayuda.

Comment: Jose, que tipo de aplicación deseas crear? que realizaría el adb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto se puede realizar de esta forma mediante:

```
   try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb ....");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Me intriga saber para que tipo de aplicación quisieras ejecutar el  [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) desde tu aplicación ya que el [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) regularmente lo ejecutas desde la linea de comandos, esto para realizar alguna acción en el dispositivo. Algo importante es que desde la linea de comandos puedes tener más privilegios que ejecutando tu proceso desde el dispositivo.

---

Amigo Jose, he visto realizaste esta pregunta:

[¿Cómo Mover Un App Del Usuario?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29013/c%C3%B3mo-mover-un-app-del-usuario)

seguramente por eso preguntas acerca del [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html), como comento anteriormente, si ejecutas desde el dispositivo probablemente no tengas los mismos privilegios y mover la aplicación probablemente no podrías realizarlo.

Ejemplo mover aplicación a memoria externa:

```
adb shell pm install -i "com.myapp.elenasys" -s -r /data/app/com.myapp.elenasys.apk
```

Comment: La aplicacion que quiero crear es como una removedora de apps a sd, Una pregunta donde escribo el comnado en .exec("aqui") y con comillas o sin comillas. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Realiza una prueba yo sinceramente no he usado el comado adb desde una app para mover aplicaciones, sería bueno nos comentaras a todos que resultados tienes. El comando se escribiría dentro de .exec( ............ );

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Es un placer ayudar, sería interesante saber que resultados tuviste al ejecutar esa acción con el ADB desde la aplicación, saludos!.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias entendí el punto si trato de de ejecutar los comandos desde la app a lo mejor no tenga el mismo efecto, entonces buscare otra forma de lograrlo. Acaso no sabrás como mostrar una lista de  apps del usuario que sea mas controlable porque el que tengo no me funciona como quiero, porque quiero mostrarlas y después al pisar click en la listView ejecute el proceso de buscar su ruta y nombre. Si sabes me seria de gran ayuda.

Comment: Ya tienes construido el ListView que carga los nombres?

Comment: Tengo el ListView que tiene android por defecto, pero dime tengo que crear mi propio estilo de ListView lo creo si es necesario. Muchas gracias por responderme