# ¿Como poder hacer que una aplicación aparezca como instalada?

Tags: android

Mi problema es que necesito poder mostrar una aplicación que mi aplicación instala manualmente copiando la dex, la data y el apk en los directorios correspondiente de la data, pero el problema es que no la reconoce como instalada.

<sub>No tengo código porque no tengo ni la mínima idea de como lograrlo.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se pueden instalar aplicaciones desde otra aplicación (hay aplicaciones en la tienda que lo hacen y también hacen backups de otras aplicaciones). Para ello hay varias formas dependiendo de la versión de Android.

- Intent que abre el fichero APK.

  Puedes intentar Instalar la aplicación de la siguiente manera:

  ```
  Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  install.setDataAndType(uri,
              manager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(downloadId));
  startActivity(install);
  ```

  Puedes encontrar el código completo en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4969421/6658955).
- Package manager

  También existe una clase llamada [Package Installer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller.html) que ofrece la habilidad de instalar aplicaciones. Para esto el código tiene un aspecto como:

  ```
  public static boolean installPackage(Context context, InputStream in, String packageName)
          throws IOException {
      PackageInstaller packageInstaller = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
      PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
              PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
      params.setAppPackageName(packageName);
      // set params
      int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
      PackageInstaller.Session session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);
      OutputStream out = session.openWrite("COSU", 0, -1);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
      int c;
      while ((c = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
          out.write(buffer, 0, c);
      }
      session.fsync(out);
      in.close();
      out.close();

      session.commit(createIntentSender(context, sessionId));
      return true;
  }

  private static IntentSender createIntentSender(Context context, int sessionId) {
          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
              context,
              sessionId,
              new Intent(ACTION_INSTALL_COMPLETE),
              0
          );
      return pendingIntent.getIntentSender();
  }
  ```

  Puedes revisar [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884956/how-to-install-update-remove-apk-using-packageinstaller-class-in-android-l). Probablemente necesites el permiso de [INSTALL_PACKAGES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INSTALL_PACKAGES).
- Usando el gestor de paquetes PM:

  ```
  pm install /sdcard/com.twitter.android-1.apk
  ```

  [Comandos utiles](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11052/what-useful-android-shell-commands-do-you-know)

La ultima forma que es la que creo tu quieres, es copiar todos los ficheros manualmente. Para explicar esto voy a traducir el post [*In Depth: Android Package Manager and Package Installer*](https://dzone.com/articles/depth-android-package-manager)

> #### ¿Qué son el gestor de paquetes y el instalador de paquetes?
>
> PackageInstaller es la aplicación predeterminada para Android para instalar interactivamente un paquete normal. PackageInstaller proporciona una interfaz de usuario para administrar aplicaciones / paquetes. PackageInstaller llama a la actividad InstallAppProgress para recibir instrucciones del usuario. InstallAppProgress le pedirá al gestor de paquetes que instale el paquete a través de installd. El código fuente está disponible en  **/ packages / apps / PackageInstaller**.
>
> El rol principal del demonio installd es recibir la solicitud del Package Manager Service a través del socket de dominio de Linux / dev / socket / installed. Installd ejecuta una serie de pasos para instalar APK con permiso de root.
>
> **Package Manager** es una API que gestiona la instalación, desinstalación y actualización de las aplicaciones. Cuando instalamos el archivo APK, el Package Manager analiza el archivo de paquete (APK) y muestra confirmación. Cuando el usuario pulsa el botón Aceptar, el Administrador de paquetes llama al método denominado "installPackage" con estos cuatro parámetros { uri, installFlags, observer, installPackageName }. Package Manager inicia un servicio denominado "paquete" y ahora todos los procesos de instalación suceden ahí. El servicio Package Manager se ejecuta en el proceso system_service y el daemon de instalación (installd) se ejecuta como un proceso nativo. Ambos comienzan en el arranque del sistema.
>
> #### ¿Cuál es el proceso de instalación del APK en detalle?
>
> El proceso siguiente se ejecuta en el servicio de gestor de paquetes.
>
> - Esperar
> - Agregar un paquete a la cola para el proceso de instalación
> - Determinar la ubicación apropiada de la instalación del paquete
> - Determinar si corresponde Instalar / Actualizar
> - Copiar el archivo apk a un directorio dado
> - Determinar el UID de la aplicación
> - Solicitar el proceso del daemon installd
> - Crear el directorio de aplicaciones y establecer permisos
> - Extraer el código dex en el directorio de caché
> - Reflejar en packages.list / system / data / packages.xml el estado más reciente de las aplicaciones instaladas
> - Enviar BroadCast al sistema junto con el nombre de la instalación. Pueden ser Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED: Si el nuevo o intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED si es actualización.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código fuente de [*Package manager está en el repositorio android*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/483f3b06ea84440a082e21b68ec2c2e54046f5a6/services/java/com/android/server/pm).
El código fuente de [*Package Parser*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/483f3b06ea84440a082e21b68ec2c2e54046f5a6/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java).
El código fuente de [*Package Installer*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/PackageInstaller/+/47fe118e0178e9d72c98073ff588ee5cf353258e/src/com/android/packageinstaller/).

Si quieres hacerlo manual, entonces debes seguir el mismo proceso con tu propio código. Generar el uid de la app, crear los usuarios, los directorios y los ficheros, actualizar los archivos que mantienen los registros de las aplicaciones instaladas y por ultimo generar un evento broadcast para que los programas que escuchan el evento de instalación de paquetes se actualicen.. como el Touchwiz de samsung o la aplicación de configuración de Android.

Otros enlaces.

[How Android Apps are Built and Run](https://github.com/dogriffiths/HeadFirstAndroid/wiki/How-Android-Apps-are-Built-and-Run)
[how to install a application in background on android](https://paulononaka.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/how-to-install-a-application-in-background-on-android/)
[What exactly happens when I install an android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773360/what-exactly-happens-when-i-install-an-android-application)

*PD: debes tener acceso a ROOT (y todo lo que eso implica) y probablemente el mismo proceso no sea compatible entre versiones distintas de Android. Y yo no he probado hacer esto, por que demanda demasiado tiempo y por que no soy tan caprichoso :P Aun así es interesante andar metido en el código fuente de Android :P*

Comment: Sigo teniendo el mismo problema el cual es: necesito poder hacer que una aplicación que  yo mismo instale moviendo los archivos correspondiente a la data se muestre como instalada y no de error al ejecutarlo. Gracias

Comment: usas un dispositivo rooteado?

Comment: Si mi aplicación solicita ese permiso. Gracias.

Comment: Sero según la [respuesta de este usuario](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39562829/6658955), crear todo manual y como usuario ROOT, posterior a un reinicio, debería bastar.

Comment: Eso ya lo he probado, lo que sucede es una actualización del sistema donde optimiza las app, pero mi requerimiento es evitar  que mi aplicación requiera tener que reiniciarse cada vez que utilice una extensión. Gracias

Comment: Una duda el código presentado del packageinstall esta dañado o solo es permisible hasta algunas versiones, porque mi aplicación solicita permiso root y estoy probando la aplicación en un emulador 4.1.2 y como yo podria implementar el intent que alerta al sistema sobre la instalación de la aplicacion. Muchas gracias por su aporte.

Comment: Veo que esta pregunta se marco como correcta, solo quiero comentar que **no hay forma de instalar la aplicación si copias un .apk en el almacenamiento interno**, se puede realizar la instalación por medio de un Intent pero únicamente si el .apk se encuentra en el almacenamiento externo, obviamente necesita saber el path. **Cambiar un dispositivo a Root no tiene relación con trabajar con el código fuente de android.**

Comment: Ok muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 4):

Copiar los dex o el .apk (de hecho únicamente se necesita el .apk) en el **almacenamiento interno** y tratar de instalarlo programaticamente no puede ser posible.

Las opciones son :

- Ejecutar la instalación desde el dispositivo por medio del instalador

https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1006430

- Instalarlo por medio del adb :

  adb install path_to_apk

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#move

---

Si se tiene el .apk en el **almacenamiento externo**, se podría realizar de esta forma, definiendo el folder donde se encuentra y el nombre del archivo .apk:

```
String DIRECTORIO_APK = "/Downloads/";
String NAME_APK = "myApplication.apk";
String MIME_TYPE = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + DIRECTORIO_APK + NAME_APK)), MIME_TYPE);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: El problema es que necesito hacerlo desde mi aplicación, pero copiando los archivos porque es mas rápido que instalando el apk no habrá una forma? . Gracias

Comment: Ah! el proceso de copiado es rápido pero la instalación es lo que tardaría de cualquier forma, recuerda que el .apk en realidad es un .zip (puedes cambiar la extensión y tratar de abrir el archivo) el proceso de instalación implica registro, instalación, creación de folders e incluso el shortcut de la instalación por esa razón, el copiado es rápido, pero si deseas realizar la instalación tardaría sin duda. Trata ejecutando el adb : http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/29072/95

Comment: Ya lo he ejecutado desde el adb y se tarda pero no existirá alguna manera de poder burlar, manipular o engañar por así decirlo al sistema para que ejecute esa app en el estado que se encuentra. Gracias

Comment: Podría ser que el .apk este en el almacenamiento externo ?, sería opción usar un Intent para ejecutar el instalador.

Comment: No,  se encuentra en la sdcard y el intent y el comando es lo mismo porque ya lo he probado. Gracias

Comment: @Abraham.P =0 La SDCard en realidad es el almacenamiento interno! =0

Comment: Si lo es. Gracias

Comment: Excelentes información y métodos de instalación de apk, tal vez esta buena respuesta ayude o facilite un problema o necesidad de otro programador desviado o confundido en su camino. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Este proceso se conoce como sideloading.

Un paso importante para poder hacerlo es activar en tu dispositivo la pestaña **Orígenes desconocidos**.

Según la marca, esta pestaña estará en:

```
inglés:  Menu -> Settings      -> Applications 
español: Menu -> Configuración -> Aplicaciones
```

o en

```
español: Menu -> Ajustes -> Ajustes adicionales -> Privacidad
```

o en

```
español: otro sitio -> te tocará a ti -> encontrarla :)
```

Luego instalas tu APK como se ha dicho en otras respuestas, abriendo directamente el archivo APK, o mediante el ADB, o mediante otro método.

Nota:

> El uso de sideloading puede ser peligroso, ya que se pueden instalar apps con código mal intencionado.

Comment: Gracias por su aporte, pero esto ya lo he hecho, mi problema actual es querer poder actualizar el listado de app instalada para que aparezca mi aplicación o realizar un proceso registro de mi app en ese listado, por la simple razón de lo que yo hago es copiar los archivos en su directorio no instalar el apk, porque el copiado es mas rápido. Gracias